# In azure logic App how to pass Cookie to Http request

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic app by calling first Http endpoint we need to get the cookie and pass to the second endpoint. But while passing second API, I am passing in header and it is sending but the response is wrong(text/html).

But When I checked by using postman it worked fine got response in JSON(application/json).

The header getting after calling second API or endpoint  through logic app ,I am getting is:

```
    {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Cache-Control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache",
            "X-Powered-By": "Undertow/1",
            "Set-Cookie": "JSESSIONID=Ntu9NMCoekk56JveKceina3FCwgNJptU4EK0GOIz.s192-169-141-210; path=/StLightControl",
            "Server": "WildFly/10",
            "Pragma": "no-cache,no-cache",
            "Date": "Tue, 12 Jun 2018 14:25:45 GMT",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Content-Length": "2585",
            "Expires": "0,0",
            "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry what are you trying to do ? extract the header from the reponse you've posted ?

Answer (score 3):

The “Add new parameter” dropdown allows you to enable a checkbox that says “Cookie” that enables you to enter the HTTP cookie (from dynamic content if you want to). You cannot enter the value straight in the dropdown, so close it down after you selected the checkbox and see a magic Cookie field appear underneath the Authentication field.

[image: Cookie authentication in Logic App]

More information to be found here: [HowTo: Call an API with cookie authentication from a Logic App](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/howto-call-an-api-with-cookie-authentication-from-a-logic-app/)