# In azure logic apps how to send Cookie to a Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic app I'm calling a http endpoint and getting cookie and i'm passing that cookie to second request. If i check run history it is sending in header while calling second endpoint but the cookie(header) is not reaching second endpoint.

**What I have tried:**

I've just tried to call second endpoint alone.So, the image i've placed below, shows that i've hardcoded the cookie value manually by calling first endpoint.

[image]

Comment: post code here that you have tried.

Comment: I've added the image of calling only second API by placing cookie in header manually after calling first API.

Comment: @vikram so you’re passing in cookie to the second endpoint successfully but its response is coming back as html/text, not application/json?

Comment: Yeah by using JAVA application and using WSO2 ESB, I have implemented the same use case it is working and returning application/json response which means the cookie is authenticated successfully. But logic app sending in header that we can see in run history but it is not reaching endpoint.

Comment: To confirm that it is not reaching i have tested it. The cookie is implemented like it'll work for only one time. So, if I manually call the second endpoint in postman with the cookie from run history of logic app, it is able to call. Which means Cookie never got sent to the endpoint.

Comment: Duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820027/in-azure-logic-app-how-to-pass-cookie-to-http-request/58064281#58064281

Answer (score 1):

If you set `Headers` in `Body` in Http2 and click `Code view` you will find that it equals to `"@outputs('HTTP')['headers']"`.

[image]

It means that you could **get key value in Http1 headers** by using `@outputs('HTTP')['headers']['Key_name']`.

[image]

The output is:
[image]

Comment: thank you for the response but my question is that it is sending in the header if you see run history but it is not reaching the endpoint. You can check in the postman it'll not cookie after the call but it shows in run history.

Comment: May be this is a bug in logic app, as i have seen many posts complaining about cookie not sending.

Comment: Did your http1 and http2 in a same domain? If not, the cookie could not reach the endpoint. Also, you could check your idea in browser. You could visit http1 and generate cookie then visit http2.

Answer (score 0):

See answer in duplicate question [In azure logic App how to pass Cookie to Http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820027/in-azure-logic-app-how-to-pass-cookie-to-http-request/58064281#58064281)

> The “Add new parameter” dropdown allows you to enable a checkbox that says “Cookie” that enables you to enter the HTTP cookie (from dynamic content if you want to).